# Windows 10 not recognizing 2nd monitor. Settings in forums are not available to me

Tags: windows-10

I have just purchased 2 screens. I have windows 10 and I had to purchase and HDMI splitter as there is only one hdmi port on my computer.

Now that both screens are up and working - they are mirroring each other. I would like to have both screen but so that I can run different programs on each and be able to to work on each at the same time....ie internet window open on one page and word on the other.

I have googled and although there have been many instructions, none are working as my computer does not detect my second screen. I have done it all. I have downloaded all the updates and drives possible. Still nothing works. THe options they suggest aren't even there.

I keep seeing people have screen 1 and 2 in Youtube videos in the display window, I do not have those, I just have drop down menus....

PLEASE HELP. Thank you

Comment: Don't think it will work.  One signal out, the split is happening at the cable.  Do you have any other video outputs? DVI or VGA?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do this with a splitter. To do what you are suggesting will require each monitor to have its own input. You likely have another input of a different type. It may be VGA, DVI or Displayport. Google these and you can see what they look like so you’ll know what you’re looking at.